# Gridview data overriden when new row is added

Tags: asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

In my setup, I have a **GridView** that I want to populate using a ***ModalPopupExtender***. The ModalPopupExtender contains a panel (ID="FlowPanel") that containsseveral controls: Labels, DropdownLists and two buttons, *Cancel* and *Submit*.

The ***Cancel*** button (ID="CancelFlowsButton") is the button that cancels the ModalPopupExtender, while the ***Submit*** button (ID="AddFlowButton) creates a new row in the GridView with data from the panel ***"FlowPanel"***.

Using my code, rows get added just fine to the GridView. However, everytime a new row is added, the data in the previously created rows get overriden with the values of the newly created row.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. As I am a beginner at ASP.NET, please bear with me, and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Default.aspx.cs code (snapshot)**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FirstFlowGridViewRow();
        }
    }

    protected void AddFlowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewFlowGridViewRow();          
        FlowModalPopupExtender.Hide();
    }


    protected void FirstFlowGridViewRow()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(int)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col4", typeof(int)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col5", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col6", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col7", typeof(int)));

        dr = table.NewRow();

        dr["Col1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col3"] = 0;
        dr["Col4"] = 0;
        dr["Col5"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col6"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col7"] = 0;
        table.Rows.Add(dr);

        ViewState["currentTable"] = table;
        FlowGridView.DataSource = table;
        FlowGridView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void AddNewFlowGridViewRow()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["currentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable currentDt = (DataTable) ViewState["currentTable"];
            DataRow currentRow = null;
            if(currentDt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for(int i = 1; i <= currentDt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    currentRow = currentDt.NewRow();

                    currentDt.Rows[i - 1]["Col1"] = NameTextBox.Text;
                    currentDt.Rows[i - 1]["Col2"] = DirectionDropDownList.SelectedValue;
                    currentDt.Rows[i - 1]["Col3"] = StartYearTextBox.Text;
                    currentDt.Rows[i - 1]["Col4"] = EndYearTextBox.Text; ;
                    currentDt.Rows[i - 1]["Col5"] = TimingDropDownList.SelectedValue;
                    currentDt.Rows[i - 1]["Col6"] = TypeDropDownList.SelectedValue;
                    currentDt.Rows[i - 1]["Col7"] = AmountTextBox.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                currentDt.Rows.Add(currentRow);
                ViewState["currentTable"] = currentDt;

                FlowGridView.DataSource = currentDt;
                FlowGridView.DataBind();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        SetPreviousFlowData();
    }

    protected void SetPreviousFlowData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["currentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable currentDt = (DataTable) ViewState["currentTable"];

            if(currentDt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < currentDt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Label LabelName = (Label)FlowGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("NameLabel");                      
                    DropDownList DropDownDirection = (DropDownList)FlowGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("GridDirectionDropDownList");
                    Label LabelStart = (Label)FlowGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("StartYearLabel");
                    Label LabelEnd = (Label)FlowGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("EndYearLabel");
                    DropDownList DropDownTiming = (DropDownList)FlowGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("GridTimingDropDownList");
                    DropDownList DropDownType = (DropDownList)FlowGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("GridTypeDropDownList");
                    Label LabelAmount = (Label)FlowGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("AmountLabel");

                    LabelName.Text = currentDt.Rows[i]["Col1"].ToString();
                    DropDownDirection.SelectedValue = currentDt.Rows[i]["Col2"].ToString();
                    LabelStart.Text = currentDt.Rows[i]["Col3"].ToString();
                    LabelEnd.Text = currentDt.Rows[i]["Col4"].ToString();
                    DropDownTiming.SelectedValue = currentDt.Rows[i]["Col5"].ToString();
                    DropDownType.SelectedValue = currentDt.Rows[i]["Col6"].ToString();
                    LabelAmount.Text = currentDt.Rows[i]["Col7"].ToString();
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Default.aspx code (snapshot)**

```
                   <table style="height: 180px; width: 755px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style7" valign="top">
                                <div style="overflow: auto; height: 200px; width: 669px">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="FlowGridView" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                        Width="577px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True"
                                        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowEditing="FlowGridView_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="FlowGridView_RowUpdating"
                                        OnRowCancelingEdit="FlowGridView_RowCancelingEdit">
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" Height="2px" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="30%" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Direction">
                                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="GridDirectionDropDownList" runat="server">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="W">Withdrawal</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="C">Contribution</asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Year">
                                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="StartYearLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Year">
                                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="EndYearLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Timing">
                                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="GridTimingDropDownList" runat="server">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="E">End of Year</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="B">Beginning of Year</asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inflation Adj.">
                                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="GridTypeDropDownList" runat="server">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="13px" Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="AmountLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" Height="10px" />
                                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <asp:Button ID="AddCashFlowButton" runat="server" Text="Add Cash Flow..." 
                                    Width="158px" />
                                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="FlowModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
                                    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="AddCashFlowButton" PopupControlID="FlowPanel"
                                    CancelControlID="CancelFlowsButton" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                                </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting data. Change the `AddNewFlowGridViewRow()` method to this:

```
protected void AddNewFlowGridViewRow()
{

    if (ViewState["currentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable currentDt = (DataTable)ViewState["currentTable"];
        DataRow currentRow = null;
        currentRow = currentDt.NewRow();

        currentRow["Col1"] = NameTextBox.Text;
        currentRow["Col2"] = DirectionDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        currentRow["Col3"] = StartYearTextBox.Text;
        currentRow["Col4"] = EndYearTextBox.Text; ;
        currentRow["Col5"] = TimingDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        currentRow["Col6"] = TypeDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        currentRow["Col7"] = AmountTextBox.Text;                            

        currentDt.Rows.Add(currentRow);
        ViewState["currentTable"] = currentDt;

        FlowGridView.DataSource = currentDt;
        FlowGridView.DataBind();
    }

    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }
    SetPreviousFlowData();
}
```

**EDIT :** 
If you want to remove the default empty row upon inserting new row, you can do like this:

```
protected void AddNewFlowGridViewRow()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["currentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable currentDt = (DataTable)ViewState["currentTable"];
        DataRow currentRow = currentDt.NewRow();

        currentRow["Col1"] = NameTextBox.Text;
        currentRow["Col2"] = DirectionDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        currentRow["Col3"] = StartYearTextBox.Text;
        currentRow["Col4"] = EndYearTextBox.Text; ;
        currentRow["Col5"] = TimingDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        currentRow["Col6"] = TypeDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        currentRow["Col7"] = AmountTextBox.Text;

        currentDt.Rows.Add(currentRow);

        if (currentDt.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            DataRow firstRow = currentDt.Rows[0];

            if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstRow["Col1"].ToString()) &&
                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstRow["Col2"].ToString()) &&
                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstRow["Col5"].ToString()) &&
                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstRow["Col6"].ToString())) &&
                (firstRow["Col3"].ToString() == "0" &&
                    firstRow["Col4"].ToString() == "0" &&
                    firstRow["Col7"].ToString() == "0"))
            {
                currentDt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        ViewState["currentTable"] = currentDt;

        FlowGridView.DataSource = currentDt;
        FlowGridView.DataBind();
    }

    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }
    SetPreviousFlowData();
}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!! But for the sake of understanding better, could you please detail how your answer solved my problem (i.e. what was I doing wrong)? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating a new row and adding it to the table, your code was looping through the existing rows and replacing them by the new data. So the table was full with the last row you added.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, how can I make the first row (the default row that appears initially upon page load) disappear once other rows with data are added?

Comment: Your post is right on and extremely helpful!! Thanks a lot for taking the time!